# Как правильно сверстать сайт, чтоб он отображался нормально и в ИЕ 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Сверстал страницу макета. Во всех браузерах выглядит нормально, кроме ИЕ 7.
Подскажите, что нужно сделать, дайте ссылку на пример или покажите код, в общем что-нибудь, где рассказывается как верстать под ИЕ 7.

Comment: Расскажите, что именно не получается

Comment: Если только пробуешь себе  верстке,то мой совет не бери в голову IE7.

Comment: заказчик требует

Comment: у меня некоторые блоки смещены вверх

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем в head

```
<!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="Screen" href="/ie.css"> <![endif]-->
```

создаем файл ie.css и прописываем там стили для IE 7

Comment: немного поздновато но всёравно этот вариант мне очень помог